# Tensor product of sheaves over weighted projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, quasicoherent-sheaves

I have read that if we have a weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}$ in general it is not true that:
$$
\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(n)\otimes \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(m)\simeq \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(n+m).
$$

Now, this is the case if $\mathbb{P}$ is just a regular projective space $\mathbb{P}^r$. Is there any result that says when this is true? Does it depend on whether the sheaves $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(n), \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(m)$ are invertible or not? What happens in easy cases like $\mathbb{P}(1,\ldots, 1,a)$?

Comment: The sheaves $\mathcal{O}(n)$ on a weighted projective space are reflexive, and it is always true that $(\mathcal{O}(n) \otimes \mathcal{O}(m))^{\vee\vee} \cong \mathcal{O}(n + m)$.

Comment: @Sasha Ok, I think I misunderstood the paper I was reading. Let us write $\mathbb{P}=\mathrm{Proj}(S)$. Is it possible that $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(n)\otimes \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(m)\simeq \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(m+n)$ but that this isomorphism is not induced by the multiplication morphism $S(n)\otimes S(m)\rightarrow S(m+n)$?